# Gatling ユーザー数と実施間隔の設定について

Tags: scala, gatling

Gatlingを使って負荷テストを行っております。

ユーザー数：1
実施間隔：600秒

```
setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1) during(600 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

という条件で負荷テストを実施しているのですが、実施すると、想定よりも早くテストが完了してしまいます。
　（例：600秒で完了させたいテストが80秒ほどで完了してしまう）

想定通りの実施間隔でテストを完了させるためにはどのようにすればよいか対処方法をご教授頂けませんでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 自分で試していませんが、以下のページの `ソークテスト (耐久テスト)` を見る限り、質問文のコードは「600秒当たり1ユーザー」という設定で動いていて、1回アクセスが発生して終了してるかもですね。公式ドキュメントなどを参照して本当に行いたい(600秒間でどのような負荷がかかってほしいのか)負荷テストの設定に変更すると良いかもしれません。 https://www.infoq.com/jp/articles/load-testing-apis-gatling/

Comment: 返信が遅くなりました。ご回答ありがとうございます。 
Gatlingは起動するとすぐに1ユーザ目の処理を行っているため、待つことなく終わってしまっているのだと思っております。
少し考えてみようと思います。教えていただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

公式ドキュメント見る限り、テストの実施時間は `scenario.during()` で指定できるようです。

https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#during

簡単なサンプルコードとしては以下の様になります。

```scala
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.language.postfixOps

class Aaa extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl("http://localhost:9000")
    .inferHtmlResources()
    .contentTypeHeader("text/xml; charset=utf-8")
    .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.42000)")

  val scn =
    scenario("aaa")
      .during(600 seconds) {
        exec(http("request").get(""))
      }

  setUp(scn.inject(rampUsers(1) during(600 seconds))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

実行結果からも600s実施されていることが分かります。

```
================================================================================
2021-06-04 14:11:02                                         600s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=135864 KO=0     )
> request                                                  (OK=33966  KO=0     )
> main.css                                                 (OK=33966  KO=0     )
> favicon.png                                              (OK=33966  KO=0     )
> hello.js                                                 (OK=33966  KO=0     )

---- aaa -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[##########################################################################]100%
          waiting: 0      / active: 0      / done: 1
================================================================================
```

コメントでも書きましたが、この600秒間でどのようなアクセスが発生してほしいかについては、`scn.inject()`の設定で調整してみてください。

https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#open-model

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。返信が空いてしまい申し訳ありません。
scenario.during()を試してみたいと思います！